# Laravel 5.4 redirect / not working

Tags: laravel-5.4

The command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

shows:

```
GET|HEAD  | /  | App\Http\Controllers\StaticController@index
```

I added following code in my StaticController controller

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->flush();

    return Redirect::route('/');
}
```

In my web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'StaticController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/logout', 'MiscController@logout');
});
```

When I click on logout link, it shows the message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
Route [/] not defined.
```

When I reload the page showing error, it redirects me to:  /login
Not able to figure out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return Redirect::route('/');
```

with

```
return redirect('/');
```

Think there is no route with name `/`

But if you prefer to use route names when redirecting, you may do this:

```
return redirect()->route('your.route.name', ['id' => $order->id]);
```